# Master's Degree in Sound Design

Tags: education, video-games

Hi everyone, in 1 year, i'm going to finish my undergraduate Music Technology program in Turkey. So after that, i want to go to school about sound design -especially on video game- for master's degree. Also, i haven't chosen which country and school would i go for this. Because i want to live in there after the master's degree, rest of my life. So what're the ideal schools in video game sound design with good curriculum, equipments and staff?

By the way, I've heard good things about VFS (Vancouver Film School) So what're your thoughts about there?

Answer (score 1):

This one´s pretty good, located in Helsinki Finland. Nice curriculum, well educated staff, awesome facilities and top notch gear.

http://mlab.taik.fi/studies/master_of_arts/sound_in_new_media/

Downside is that it´s very sought after program and very hard to get in...

Comment: Just to add something about this course and your interest in video games - firstly the university has just started a new masters program in game design that runs alongside the sound masters, and speaking from experience, the professors are well connected with the industry.

Answer (score 1):

NFTS just outside London is regarded as one of the best. Being one of the best you cannot just get in straight after University though.

You will be required to show you have worked a bit in your field, be it directing, sound or DOP and create a suitable portfolio.

It's extremely hard to get into but definitely worth trying. I've considered it myself, it's just very expensive.

Comment: NFTS is really worth attending.

Comment: NFTS is number 10 according to this new list.

http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/25-best-film-schools-rankings-215714?utm_source=SilverpopMailing&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Compose%20-%20new_special_reports_thr_filmschools_072711_500px%20%281%29%20%281%29&utm_content=

Comment: Too biased to American film schools but I guess Hollywood's the measure for success here.

Answer (score 1):

The MSc at the University of Edinburgh is really good. Great facilities and the director Martin Parker really cares about the craft and his pupils. (pretty sure Andrew Spitz was a couple years ahead of me there too :-)

Comment: I'm starting on there this September.  So quandam excited.